# Get structure of variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Running `println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)` in the jenkins console returns lots of useful stuff like:

```
[Plugin:external-monitor-job, Plugin:docker-workflow, 
 Plugin:pipeline-rest-api, Plugin:javadoc, 
 Plugin:resource-disposer, Plugin:conditional-buildstep, ...
]
```

I want to see the class structure. Where can I find the reference for those classes? Can I generate it? Is it possible to represent those classes like the the variables view in Eclipse, where I can expand all the subclasses and functions?

Those information's are really use full for creating pipeline scripts.

Answer (score 0):

https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html
... and so on.

Maybe some could mention, in a comment how to ask for this information the right way. Is it a api-reference, a class description, a ... ?